# Trouble creating database file using sqlite3 on mac mavericks from command line

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I am trying to create a database in `sqlite3` by running the following command:

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

Once `sqlite3` opens, I get the following error:

```
Error: unable to open database "test.db": unable to open database file
```

Any suggestions as to how to fix this problem? The end goal is to have a database that is saved and can be accessed through a php script.

Comment: What is the current directory when you execute the `sqlite3` command? Do you have write permission for this directory?

Comment: I'm in the sqlite directory, but I'm not sure how to check if I have write permissions in that directory.

Comment: I changed directories and now it works! Thank you!